# Add newline only on overflow

Tags: html, css

i want a text line come to new line when it overflow only(no new line for spaces). i am able to make this using

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

but when the container has only space to occuppy this text, then the text overflows. i want to make this to newline when overflow by keeping the css white-space:nowrap;

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you remove `white-space: nowrap` it works exactly as you want. Explain better your problem and provide a working example, otherwise this will be closed as offtopic.

Comment: Please add more detail to specifying your problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4pb53enk/

Comment: when making it responsive, The Hello line will over flow out of container. i want make it to new line when over flow.

Comment: why i added white-space css is , i want to keep a block of text together without breaking on spaces.